# Что за -MD -MMF опции для g++?

Tags: gcc, g++

Всем привет! Обьясните пожалуйста, что это опции -MD -MMF в gcc, g++. Я часто их вижу в сгенерированных premake5, CMake Мейкфайлах. Но по ним практически никакой информации. Я нашел их обьяснение на gcc.gnu.org, но я не смог понять, что оно значит. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эти параметры нужны, чтобы заставить `gcc` генерировать специальные файлы зависимостей (`*.d`) для каждого объектника, которые потом можно включить в `Makefile`.

---

При ручном написании `Makefile`'ов, если пытаться указать зависимости в виде:

```
foo.o: foo.c
    gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

то возникает проблема, что `foo.o` не будет пересобран, если изменить один из хедеров, включённых в `foo.c`, напримeр `foo.h`. Можно указывать эти зависимости вручную:

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h
    gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

но это довольно нудно.

Собственно одним из решений этой проблемы в и являются файлы зависимостей. Мы запускаем компилятор, чтобы он сгенерировал `*.d`-файл, а потом загружаем из него правила, чтобы явно не прописывать все хедеры:

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.d
    gcc -c foo.c -o foo.o

foo.d: foo.c
    gcc -M -MF foo.d foo.c

include foo.d
```

Сам файл зависимостей по факту является `Makefile`'ом и будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
foo.o: foo.h bar.h
```

---

В остальном, что именно делает каждый конкретный флаг из `-M`-флагов должно быть очевидно из их описания. Как всё это более практично применять в купе GNU Make/gcc можно посмотреть в [этой статейке](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/). А как именно это используют другие системы сборки — дело их внутреннего устройства.

---

PS: что такое `-MMF` я не знаю, но подозреваю, что подразумевалось `-M -MF` или `-MMD`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тогда изменение `*.d`-файла е будет тригерить пересборку объектника... в данном случае в принципе это не должно происходить, так что я оставлю это на вкусовщину... а `-include` — т.к. правило для сборки файла есть, то оно всегда должно отрабатывать и файл включаться, так что единственный практический эффект от `-include`, который я могу представить, — он может замаскировать ошибку опечатки...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, не возьмусь утверждать о всеобщности, но гнутый `make` проглатывает это нормально, включая файл только после его обновления...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, дык, перед `include` добавь правило для сборки: `1.d:` // `  touch 1.d` и не будет ошибки... `make` тебе об этом прямым текстом говорит...

Comment: Все, пардон, я понял. Я настолько привык, что `.d` и `.o` создаются одной командой (`-MD`), что не стал нормально читать ответ. Если у вас отдельная цель под `.d`, то да.

Answer (score 1):

В соседнем ответе объяснили, зачем эти флаги нужны, и показали пример, как ими пользоваться.

Но есть более простой способ. Вместо двух правил достаточно написать одно:

```
foo.o: foo.c
    gcc foo.c -c -o foo.o -MMD -MP # Остальные флаги компилятора сюда же.

-include foo.d
```

Это объединяет компиляцию и генерацию `.d`-файла в один шаг, так что должно быть немного быстрее. И писать меньше.

Comment: Спасибо! Это тот пример, который я хотел